# .htaccess : remove index.php in the url if there is no querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing

I want to remove index.php in the url if there is no querystring.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule index.php http://www.domain.fr [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?category=$1&region=$2 [L,QSA]
```

www.domain.fr/index.php         => ok, redirects well to www.domain.fr

www.domain.fr/index.php?i=1     => ok, no redirection

www.domain.fr/category/region/ (if entered manually in the url)  =>  ok, no redirection

www.domain.fr/category/region/ (if posted via a php form)  => redirect (and shouldn't) to www.domain.fr

Here is my php form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <select id="category" name="category">..</select>
  <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

and the code of this form (at the top of the page):

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $category = $_POST['category']; 
    $region = $_POST['region'];
    header('Location: http://www.domain.fr/$category/$region/');
    exit;
}
```

If I remove the cond RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ the php form redirects well to www.domain.fr/category/region, but if I put the cond it redirects always to www.domain.fr,

any idea ?

Comment: Do you have more rules other than these?

Comment: I use those rules after:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
    RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=SD:${vhost:%{HTTP_HOST}}]

When I remove the cond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ (the 2 last lines), the parameters are correctly sent, when I put this rule, the parameters are lost

Comment: You need to update the code in question as it is difficult to understand it from comments.

Comment: sure, please find the updated code. When the url is www.domain.fr/category/region/  it redirects to www.domain.fr (works well if only www.domain.fr/index.php)

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of rules is the problem, keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[^?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=302,L]

RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=SD:${vhost:%{HTTP_HOST}}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&region=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: when I type www.domain.fr/category/region/ it is redirected (and shouldn't) to www.domain.fr, any idea ?

Comment: Try updated code and make sure to test this in a new browser.

Comment: grr that makes me crazy, still the same, now it removes index.php  even if there are parameters, grrrr, frankly if you find the solution I'll offer you a beer!:)

Comment: ok another update. Make sure you don't have any other rule or any other .htaccess anywhere.

Comment: Indeed it's like just a little thing is missing, that doesn't redirect when I use www.domain.fr/index.php?i=1 but still redirect (and shouldn't) with www.domain.fr/category/region/

Comment: Is `/category/region/` a real directory?

Comment: What happens you directly enter this URL: `www.domain.fr/category/region/` in your browser?

Comment: it redirects to www.domain.fr (and shouldn't). When I remove the conds with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ the url www.domain.fr./category/region works well.. I add this rule to remove index.php, it redirects www.domain.fr./category/region to www.domain.fr

Comment: Are you sure you have `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[^?] [NC]` this line also? Also test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: yes I've copy/paste your code and each time I clean and refresh my browser, but I've discover sthg new, I've updated the question, you'll probably understand

Answer (score 0):

Anubhava I've found the answer!!!

the problem was just about the php form, it's needed to remove:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
```

The solution is simply:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

but than kyou very much Anubhava!